# Inno Setup: Function to select a component

Tags: inno-setup

I have a small problem. I need that a page is displayed when you select one or two components. But the other is not work only with a single component seems to have an effect. I leave the code that I'm working.

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVerName=My Program v.1.2
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Types]
Name: full; Description: Full installation
Name: compact; Description: Compact installation
Name: custom; Description: Custom installation; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: program; Description: Program Files; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: help; Description: Help File; Types: full
Name: readme; Description: Readme File; Types: full
Name: readme\en; Description: English; Flags: exclusive
Name: readme\de; Description: German; Flags: exclusive

[Code]
var
  Page1: TWizardPage;

Procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page1:= CreateCustomPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Custom wizard page 1', 'TButton');
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Case PageID of
    Page1.ID: Result:= not IsComponentSelected('help');
    Page1.ID: Result:= not IsComponentSelected('readme\de'); //  It does not work
  end;
end;
```

A greeting and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to write more complex conditions, use logical operators for that. In this case you wanted to use the `and` operator:

```pascal
Result := not IsComponentSelected('help') and not IsComponentSelected('readme\de');
```

Which can be read as:

> Skip page if "help" component is not selected and "readme\de"
> component is not selected as well. In human language it could be, skip
> page if neither "help" nor "readme\de" component is selected.

Your code so can be simplified to this:

```pascal
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // skip the page if it's our custom page and neither "help" nor "readme\de"
  // component is selected, do not skip otherwise
  Result := (PageID = Page1.ID) and (not IsComponentSelected('help') and
    not IsComponentSelected('readme\de'));
end;
```

One final note (and a possible cause of problems), beware of switching on the same identifier in `case` statements. Compiler should not allow you doing this but unfortunately does, e.g. this compiles:

```pascal
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 1;
  case I of
    1: MsgBox('Case switch 1.1', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    1: MsgBox('Case switch 1.2', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

But only the first switch value statement executes, so you'll never see the message *"Case switch 1.2"*.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you as always, I don't know what I would do without you, Lama :D