# Inno setup: don't show option if it is not checked

Tags: inno-setup

After looking at this example [Inno Setup: Function to select a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039798/inno-setup-function-to-select-a-component) I've added another option to my code but what I'm trying to do (and I don't know if it is possible) is that if in the components section an option hasn't been marked, I don't want it to appear in **Page1.Add('help');** or **Page1.Add('readme\de');**

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVerName=My Program v.1.2
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Types]
Name: full; Description: Full installation
Name: compact; Description: Compact installation
Name: custom; Description: Custom installation; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: program; Description: Program Files; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: help; Description: Help File; Types: full
Name: readme; Description: Readme File; Types: full
Name: readme\en; Description: English; Flags: exclusive
Name: readme\de; Description: German; Flags: exclusive

[Code]
var
  Page1: TInputOptionWizardPage;

Procedure BackupCheckCreate();
    var
      StaticText: TNewStaticText;
begin
  Page1 := CreateInputOptionPage(wpReady, 'Optional Actions Test', 
                                          'Which actions should be performed?', 
                                          'Please select all optional actions you want to be performed, then click Next.',  False, False);

  Page1.Add('help');
  Page1.Add('readme\de');

  Page1.Values[0] := False;
  Page1.Values[1] := False;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (PageID = Page1.ID) and (not IsComponentSelected('help') and not IsComponentSelected('readme\de'));
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  BackupCheckCreate();
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to hide items from [`TInputOptionWizardPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputOptionWizardPage) or generally any custom page at this time. So conditional showing certain check box items on your options page by selected components is not an easy task. So before digging into some hacky ways I would suggest you another way.

From the caption of the page you are creating it looks like you need the [`[Tasks]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection) section. This section allows you to create additional task check boxes with simple binding to the selected components. Check this example:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Types]
Name: full; Description: Full installation
Name: compact; Description: Compact installation
Name: custom; Description: Custom installation; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: main; Description: "Program Files"; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: backup; Description: "Backup DB"; Types: full
Name: restore; Description: "Restore DB"; Types: full

[Tasks]
; if "backup" component is selected, these two tasks appear
Name: backuptask1; Description: "Backup 1"; GroupDescription: "Backup Tasks:"; Components: backup
Name: backuptask2; Description: "Backup 2"; GroupDescription: "Backup Tasks:"; Components: backup
; if "restore" component is selected, these two tasks appear
Name: restoretask1; Description: "Restore 1"; GroupDescription: "Restore Tasks:"; Components: restore
Name: restoretask2; Description: "Restore 2"; GroupDescription: "Restore Tasks:"; Components: restore
```

Comment: That's the idea I have but I need to restore several files once the installer has finished installing and I don't how to do it using tasks.

Thanks.